# PHP SQL search systems

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I am trying to build a search system. I used a mySQL system but I have little experience and I do not quite get it.

- I want to search by the field in the database called post_title and then get the URL, date
- I would also like to be able to search by tags. For that we need to join the table wp_term_relationships which will give us a column with post id's in it and  a column with tag id's. From that we can then work out which tags apply.

My attempt failed miserably with FATAL ERROR

```
<?php 

$proto = $_GET['proto'];
$terms = $_GET['f'];

if($proto == 'inline'){

    $searchpattern = mysql_real_escape_string(strtoupper($terms));

    $list = mysql_query("SELECT    id, 
           post_title,  post_date
 FROM      wp_posts 
 WHERE     post_title LIKE '%$searchpattern%'
)
    ORDER BY post_date;");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($list)) {
    $title = $row['post_title'];
    $date =  $row['post_date'];
    $url =  $row['guid'];

    $date = date($date, 'd M Y');

    $return .= '<li>
                <a href="#sidebar3" onClick="slide(this); return false" title="" rel="'.$id.'" style="line-height:16px;">'.$firstname.' '.$lastname.'<br /><span style="font-size:10px; color:#555;">'.$email.'</span></a>
            </li>



            <div class="title"><b>SEARCH RESULTS</b></div>
    <a href="'.$url.'"><img src=""/>'. $title .' - <span>'. $date .'</span></a>';

}

}

?>
```

Comment: What did the fatal error say?

Comment: Could you copy/paste the error? Also, why do you have a bracket ")" in your query?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $list = mysql_query("SELECT id,  post_title,  post_date 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_title LIKE '%$searchpattern%') ORDER BY post_date;");
```

You have unexpected ")" before the "ORDER" operator.

Comment: The second part of your answer is incorrect. It would be okay to leave the single quotes around search pattern as long as the entire query is in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You have an open bracket before the ORDER BY. Maybe that's what causing the problem